# How can I crop an image beyond image boundary like I want to make a 1:1 image from a 4:3 image by adding transparent/white margins to it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, image-manipulation

Currently, I am using 'react-image-crop' package to crop my images. But the issue I am facing right now is that I need a 1:1 company logo to be uploaded by the client but if the shape of the image is not a square then the user will not be able to upload the whole logo and image cropping library will crop it to 1:1 and remove/strip some part of it. Whereas I want to make it like WhatsApp profile photo upload where it allows you to crop/reshape an image beyond its boundaries in order to make it 1:1 and add some blur. I just want to add white/transparent background to newly added space. Please let me know if there is a way to achieve this using 'react-image-crop' or any other package.

*Side Note: Actually I need a 5:2 image instead of 1:1. 1:1 is easy to imagine/visualise that's why I took that example.*

> this is what my component looks like:

```
    export default function ImageCrop (props){
        const [img, setUpImg] = useState()
        const imgRef = useRef(null)
        const [crop, setCrop] = useState({ unit: 'px', width: 200, aspect: 5 / 2 })
        const [previewUrl, setPreviewUrl] = useState()
        
    
        useEffect(() => {
            
            onSelectFile(props.file)
        }
        ,[props.file])
        const onSelectFile = file => {
          
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.addEventListener('load', () => setUpImg(reader.result));
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          }
        
      
        const onLoad = useCallback(img => {
          imgRef.current = img;
        }, []);
      
        const makeClientCrop = async crop => {
          if (imgRef.current && crop.width && crop.height) {
            const cropped = await getCroppedImg(imgRef.current, crop, props.file.name);
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(previewUrl);
              setPreviewUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(cropped));
              props.updateBuffer(cropped)
             

 console.log(cropped)
        
      }
    };
  
    function getCroppedImg(image, crop, fileName) {
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        const scaleX = image.naturalWidth / image.width;
        const scaleY = image.naturalHeight / image.height;
        canvas.width = crop.width;
        canvas.height = crop.height;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
       
        ctx.drawImage(
          image,
          crop.x * scaleX,
          crop.y * scaleY,
          crop.width * scaleX,
          crop.height * scaleY,
          0,
          0,
          crop.width,
          crop.height,
        );
       
        // As Base64 string
        // const base64Image = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
       
        // As a blob
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          canvas.toBlob(blob => {
            blob.name = fileName;
            resolve(blob);
          }, 'image/jpeg', 1);
        });
      }
   
    return (
      <div className="App">
        
        <ReactCrop
          src={img}
          onImageLoaded={onLoad}
          crop={crop}
          onChange={c => setCrop(c)}
          onComplete={makeClientCrop}
          style={{width: '50%'}}
        />
        {previewUrl && <img alt="Crop preview" src={previewUrl} />}
      </div>
    )
    }
```

Comment: Adjust the size of the canvas to match your `1:1` / `5:2` aspect ratio (`canvas.width = ...; canvas.height: ...;`) and draw the image in the center of the canvas instead of the upper left corner (`0, 0`)

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you initialise the canvas dimensions in the getCroppedImg() method you could take the longest side of the loaded image and create a square canvas based on that value, then just centre the image horizontally or vertically accordingly

[image]

May be add extra pixels to W as a way of a margin to give you more room, and centre as suggested by Andreas in the comments

Comment: Is this hand-drawn "answer" really an answer?

Comment: thanks for your answer. I had no clue about canvas and whats under the hood of this library, I just used the library and copy-pasted the snippet from their website. But now at least I know what I need to look for and how to get it done. thanks for inversing you time and effort. Will figure it out! Thank you so much once again

Comment: @Andreas this hand-drawn answer is not the exact solution/code which I need but it still gave me an idea/visualisation about what to do. thanks for your contribution Andreas and Ricardo Sanchez. Will be great if can get the exact code solution though :)

Comment: @JasmohanSingh Thank you for the vote, I do appreciated, but by accepting an answer too early you block yourself from other people's help. I suggest to leave the question open for a couple of days and even if someone post something that looks promising try to code it first to see if it works and if your new attempt does not then update your question with the new code and comment on it so we can further assist. With my answer I just wanted to illustrate a possible solution, it was quicker to draw something than writing a long comment.

Comment: okay! I have unchecked the accept answer option. And thanks for your guidance and I will try you solution and get back to you with a feedback sir. Thanks